# Inductance of loop to a square wire? What is the induced current and the induced $\bar E$?

Tags: electromagnetism

*I am practising for the elementary-physics -course Tfy-0.1064, this puzzle is a simplified version of the problem 3A [here](http://tenttiarkisto.fi/exams/9916.1.pdf) (sorry not in English). My basic idea here is to understand a scenario with one loop and then understand the solenoid case.*

Suppose a circle around the square of 20-cm-side and $\frac{dB}{dt}=35\frac{mT}{s}$ in the circle, please, see the picture below. What is the induced current and the induced $\bar E$ to the square by the circle?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Calculations**

We are going to use Biot-Savart

$$\Delta \bar B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi} \frac{I \Delta\bar l\times \hat r}{r^2}$$.

I have used books such as "Matter and Interactions 3rd Edition" by Chabay (particularly pages around 721) and "Introduction to Electrodynamics" by Griffiths (particularly pages around 78 and around 322).

**3A**

> **What is the induced EMF?**
>
> > $\frac{dB}{dt}=35 mT/s$
>
> Assume $\frac{dB}{dt}:=\frac{\partial B}{dt}$. Now by Faraday's law
>   $\nabla\times \bar E = -\frac{\partial\bar B}{\partial t}$ and now by
>   Stokes -theorem:
>
> > $$emf=\oint\bar E\cdot d\bar l = -\int\int_A \frac{\partial\bar B}{dt}\cdot d\bar A  \\=-\frac{\partial\bar B}{dt} 20^2$$
>
> so $$ emf =-\frac{\partial\bar B}{dt} 20^2 (cm)^2=-(20cm)^2 35 mT/s$$
>
> Griffiths about the page 322 covers this issue, reading... history with something about the magnetic field and Biot-Savart but not apparently needed for this question.
>
> TODO 1: how can I get the electric field?
>
> TODO 2: how can I get the current?

**Other questions in the attachment**

> **3B: potential between corners assuming static-field -approximation**
>
> > $$V(\bar r)=\oint\bar E\cdot d\bar l$$ where $\theta\in[0,\pi/2]$ and, since potential does not depend on the path, you can choose any
> >     path like along the circle the easy one. Use the solution of $\bar E$
> >     from the 3A.
>
> **3C: "Dynamic field cannot precisely be approximated with static potential, why?"**
>
> Because changing magnetic field have different characteristics to static fields such as the inductance. (Not sure, perhaps some better explanation exist).

**Conclusion**

Todo.

Comment: ...perhaps I could use $\bar S=\bar E\times\bar B$, somehow?!

Comment: Griffitts "Introduction to electrodynamics" p.307 has an equation $\oint\bar E\cdot d\bar{l}=\frac{-d\phi}{dt}=-\pi a^2\frac{dB}{dt}$ in some situation, I need to understand the flux better here...reading. Faraday -law that $emf=\frac{d\phi}{dt}$?!

Comment: ...Faraday law is according to my teacher easier way of doing this...thinking..